# how to display children in Cascader Ant Design ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having problems how to display data from categorySubResponses and categorySubChildResponses, below the console.log

[image]

dreams like this cascader are taken from dummy data

[image]

Now there are no children

[image]

I use ant design **`https://ant.design/components/cascader/`**

I put the code in **`codesanbox.io`** and the link

```
https://codesandbox.io/embed/q-56619059-so-8dk0z
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to `.map()` `categorySubResponses` and `categorySubResponses` to create the values and labels for each array.

```
const options = this.state.allCategory.map(category => ({
  value: category.id,
  label: category.name,
  children: category.categorySubResponses && category.categorySubResponses.map(child => ({
    value: child.id,
    label: child.name,
    children: child.categorySubChildResponses && child.categorySubChildResponses.map(innerChild => ({
      value: innerChild.id,
      label: innerChild.name
    })) || []
  })) || []
}));
```

code clean up

```
createSubChildren = (children = []) => {
  return (
    (children &&
      children.map(child => ({
        value: child.id,
        label: child.name
      }))) ||
    []
  );
};

createChildren = (children = []) => {
  return (
    children &&
    children.map(child => ({
      value: child.id,
      label: child.name,
      children: this.createSubChildren(child.categorySubChildResponses)
    }))
  ) || [];
};

const options = this.state.allCategory.map(category => ({
  value: category.id,
  label: category.name,
  children: this.createChildren(category.categorySubResponses)
}));
```

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/q-56619059-so-mrj1u)